# How to interpolate a 2D surface using Scipy for Matplotlib rendering?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Given a 2D surface with few points that is displayed using Matplotlib:

[image: Matplotlib 3D surface]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})

x = np.arange(0, 4, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 4, 1)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.array([
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 3, 2, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 0]])

surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=cm.cool)
plt.show()
```

How can I interpolate the data to make the surface smoother? Ideally, I would want to use a spline interpolation (similar to [this example](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/GlobalBSplineSurfaceInterpolation/)). Consequently, I tried to use [`interpolate.bisplrep` from Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#d-spline-representation-procedural-bisplrep) but got various `TypeError: len(x)==len(y)==len(z) must hold` errors. How can I prepare the data?

Comment: It's only a 2D surface if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Matplotlib calls it a [3D surface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html) while Scipy calls it a [2-D surface](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#d-spline-representation-procedural-bisplrep). Not sure which one is technically correct as I would expect a 2D surface to be a plane.

Comment: A plane is a special case of a surface, I think. There can also be surfaces like you have here with local curvature. Surfaces as we know them are 2D objects embedded in 3D space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`interpolate.bisplrep` requires that the `x, y` edges are arranged using a `meshgrid`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})

x = np.arange(0, 4, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 4, 1)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.array([
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 3, 2, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 0]])

# new grid is 40x40
xnew = np.linspace(0, 3, num=40)
ynew = np.linspace(0, 3, num=40)
tck = interpolate.bisplrep(x, y, z, s=0)
znew = interpolate.bisplev(xnew, ynew, tck)

xnew, ynew = np.meshgrid(xnew, ynew)

surf = ax.plot_surface(xnew, ynew, znew, cmap=cm.cool)
plt.show()
```

[image: Matplotlib 3D surface interpolated]